# ORA-19011 in Select in oracle

Tags: select, oracle11g

I have a a select statement which throws error

**ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small**

The select is as below

```
SELECT Substr(Rtrim (Xmlagg (Xmlelement (e, Concat(message_text, ' '))).extract 
                     ( 
                            '//text()'), 
                            ' '), 0, 256) message_text, 
       mobile_number, 
       tran_date, 
       parent_tran_acct_no 
FROM   custom.mobee_push_sms_drc 
WHERE  bank_id = '43' 
       AND status = 'A' 
       AND mobile_number <> '243' 
       AND mobile_number LIKE '243%' 
GROUP  BY mobile_number, 
          tran_date, 
          parent_tran_acct_no
```

Please help to correct the sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're missing `GetClobVal`:

```
  SELECT SUBSTR (
            RTRIM (
               XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, CONCAT (MESSAGE_TEXT, ' '))).EXTRACT (
                  '//text()').GetClobVal (),                                      --> here
               ' '),
            0,
            256)
            MESSAGE_TEXT,
         mobile_number,
         tran_date,
         parent_tran_acct_no
    FROM custom.mobee_push_sms_drc
   WHERE     bank_id = '43'
         AND status = 'A'
         AND mobile_number <> '243'
         AND mobile_number LIKE '243%'
GROUP BY mobile_number, tran_date, parent_tran_acct_no
```

Without it, Oracle is trying to convert `XMLtype` into `VARCHAR2` and not `CLOB` so the result can't fit.